# ls -l | grep list files

Tags: macos, grep, ls

I would like to list files with character `é` I execute this command:

```
ls -l | grep é
```

and no results. Directory contents:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff     5020  3 may 11:48 begin
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff     0 13 jun 08:47 canté
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff     0 13 jun 08:47 centré
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff     5020  3 may 11:48 end
```

locale configuration

```
LANG="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Running command on Mac Os X 10.7.3. Is something wrong?

Answer (score 5):

A character like "é" can be represented in Unicode in two different ways.  It can be a single, precomposed Unicode character, LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE U+00E9, or it can be decomposed as two characters, LATIN SMALL LETTER E U+0065 followed by COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT U+0301.

On Mac OS X, the file system APIs always normalize to a special variant of Normalization Form D (NFD). In proper NFD, all characters that can be decomposed are.  In the variant of NFD used by the Mac OS X file system APIs, some characters are left precomposed for backward compatibility with legacy volumes.

Anyway, I suspect the form for the character as entered in Terminal is different from the form being output by `ls`.  I would compare the difference between `ls -l | hexdump -C` and `echo -n é | hexdump -C`. (In both cases, you'll get UTF-8. So, U+00e9 will appear as c3 a9 while U+0065 U+0301 will appear as 65 cc 81.)

---

Update: with a little testing, I found this works:

```
ls -l | grep $(printf "e\xcc\x81")
```

This, which is akin to sarnold's suggestion, also works:

```
ls -l *$(printf "e\xcc\x81")*
```

Basically, I'm using `printf` in a subshell as a means of entering the precise bytes sequence used in the file names. Typing the character in the normal way produces a different byte sequence which doesn't match.

Comment: My suggestion, in my now-deleted answer, was `ls -l *é*`. Short, simple, and doesn't work on OS X.

Comment: I should say that the normalization of the form is peculiar to Mac OS X, but the potential for a mismatch between an "é" entered via keyboard and an "é" in a filename is inherent to Unicode. So your suggestion might very well not work on any system using a Unicode encoding.

Comment: If you're using bash, you can also use `ls -l *$'e\xcc\x81'*`.

Comment: Ah, great! I knew there must be such a thing, but didn't know what it was. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that works:

```
ls -l | iconv -f UTF-8-MAC -t UTF-8 | grep é
```

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution that's working for you, but it is still dependent on exactly what normalization form is produced when typing or pasting the "é" into Terminal. That is, you've re-normalized the output of `ls`, but it's essentially arbitrary what your `grep` is actually looking for.